# Can I implement clustering with just 2 servers and one NAS?

Tags: sql-server-2008, windows, clustering

I have the following architecture, it consists in only 2 servers, connected to a NAS.

[image]

I'm having trouble in implementing clustering because I can't have a domain controller in any of them (if I do the sql server complains...). Is there a way to implement clustering with these limitations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clustering doesn't support using a NAS.

Current versions of SQL Server don't support using a NAS for storage.

SQL doesn't like being installed on a domain controller.

I don't think that clustering is supported on a domain controller any more.

You'll want to look at database mirroring and having a witness doing automatic failover.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [mirroring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189852.aspx), not clustering?

[MSDN difference overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510414.aspx), a summary:

- mirroring is per database vs per instance
- mirroring is 2 instances with own files, clustering is one set of files owned by active node
- clustering has stricter hardware requirements

Comment: I'm also considering it, I was just wondering if this is possible or if I'm missing something. Because this would do the automatic failover without a 3rd machine as a witness

Comment: @RagnaRock: you can use the free SQL Server Express as the witness which may be useful. But it does get around the DC limitation. Or use a 3rd machine for the DC and witness